# How to setup FFTW with threads and different precisions?

Tags: multithreading, fftw

I need to use FFTW with different arithmetic precisions and multithreaded plans.

I need to setup multithreading for all precisions? Like this:

```
fftwf_init_threads();
fftwf_plan_with_nthreads(nthreads);
fftw_init_threads();
fftw_plan_with_nthreads(nthreads);
fftwl_init_threads();
fftwl_plan_with_nthreads(nthreads);
```

Or writing this in my *start* routine

```
fftw_init_threads();
fftw_plan_with_nthreads(nthreads);
```

will be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fftw libraries for different precisions are completely independent from one another. Hence, ***you need to setup multithreading for all precisions*** by calling the corresponding function of fftw:

```
int nbthreads=2;
fftw_init_threads();
fftw_plan_with_nthreads(nbthreads);
fftwf_init_threads();
fftwf_plan_with_nthreads(nbthreads);
fftwq_init_threads();
fftwq_plan_with_nthreads(nbthreads);

...

fftw_cleanup_threads();
fftwf_cleanup_threads();
fftwq_cleanup_threads();
```

Here is a sample code to convinve you. It can be compiled by `gcc main.c -o main -lfftw3_threads -lfftw3 -lfftw3f_threads -lfftw3f -lfftw3q_threads -lfftw3q -lm -lpthread -Wall` on Unix, once the corrponding libraries are built.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <fftw3.h>

int main ( ){
    int n = 40000000;
    int nf = n*2;
    int nq =n/32;

    fftw_complex *in;
    fftw_complex *in2;
    fftw_complex *out;
    fftw_plan plan_backward;
    fftw_plan plan_forward;

    fftwf_complex *inf;
    fftwf_complex *in2f;
    fftwf_complex *outf;
    fftwf_plan plan_backwardf;
    fftwf_plan plan_forwardf;

    fftwq_complex *inq;
    fftwq_complex *in2q;
    fftwq_complex *outq;
    fftwq_plan plan_backwardq;
    fftwq_plan plan_forwardq;

    //thread parameters
    int nbthreads=2;
    fftw_init_threads();
    fftw_plan_with_nthreads(nbthreads);
    fftwf_init_threads();
    fftwf_plan_with_nthreads(nbthreads);
    fftwq_init_threads();
    fftwq_plan_with_nthreads(nbthreads);

    in = fftw_malloc ( sizeof ( fftw_complex ) * n );
    out = fftw_malloc ( sizeof ( fftw_complex ) * n );

    inf = fftwf_malloc ( sizeof ( fftwf_complex ) * nf );
    outf = fftwf_malloc ( sizeof ( fftwf_complex ) * nf );

    inq = fftwq_malloc ( sizeof ( fftwq_complex ) * nq );
    outq = fftwq_malloc ( sizeof ( fftwq_complex ) * nq);

    // forward fft
    plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_1d ( n, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE );
    fftw_execute ( plan_forward );

    plan_forwardf = fftwf_plan_dft_1d ( nf, inf, outf, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE );
    fftwf_execute ( plan_forwardf );

    plan_forwardq = fftwq_plan_dft_1d ( nq, inq, outq, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE );
    fftwq_execute ( plan_forwardq );

    // backward fft
    in2 = fftw_malloc ( sizeof ( fftw_complex ) * n );
    plan_backward = fftw_plan_dft_1d ( n, out, in2, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE );
    fftw_execute ( plan_backward );

    in2f = fftwf_malloc ( sizeof ( fftwf_complex ) * nf );
    plan_backwardf = fftwf_plan_dft_1d ( nf, outf, in2f, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE );
    fftwf_execute ( plan_backwardf );

    in2q = fftwq_malloc ( sizeof ( fftwq_complex ) * nq );
    plan_backwardq = fftwq_plan_dft_1d ( nq, outq, in2q, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE );
    fftwq_execute ( plan_backwardq);

    fftw_cleanup_threads();
    fftw_destroy_plan ( plan_forward );
    fftw_destroy_plan ( plan_backward );

    fftw_free ( in );
    fftw_free ( in2 );
    fftw_free ( out );

    fftwf_cleanup_threads();
    fftwf_destroy_plan ( plan_forwardf );
    fftwf_destroy_plan ( plan_backwardf );

    fftwf_free ( inf );
    fftwf_free ( in2f );
    fftwf_free ( outf );

    fftwq_cleanup_threads();
    fftwq_destroy_plan ( plan_forwardq);
    fftwq_destroy_plan ( plan_backwardq );

    fftwq_free ( inq );
    fftwq_free ( in2q );
    fftwq_free ( outq );

    return 0;
}
```

You can comment `fftwq_init_threads(); fftwq_plan_with_nthreads(nbthreads);` and `fftwq_cleanup_threads();` and monitor cpu usage to check that fftw will not use multithreading for quad precision in this case.

To build fftw3 for different precisions using [intel simd sse2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2), do:

```
./configure --enable-threads --enable-shared --enable-sse2
make 
make install
./configure --enable-threads --enable-shared --enable-sse2 --enable-float
make 
make install
./configure --enable-threads --enable-shared --enable-quad-precision
make
make install
```

There is no sse2 support for quad precision.